# How to release all locks held by a dying process in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, mutex, semaphore

I would like to implement a feature in the Linux kernel where all kernel-space locks (i.e., mutexes and semaphores) held by a dying user-space process are released.

How do I do that properly? I have a good idea on how to do it, but I would like to suggestions to come up with the best solution.

Thanks.

Comment: "I would like to suggestions" - Stack Overflow is a wrong place for collecting suggestions. From me: As current Linux kernel implementation doesn't track mutexes hold by a process, you need to modify task structure (for add this tracking), possibly mutex structure, and modify a code of acquiring/releasing the mutex.

Comment: Also, there is a little help in stability to auto-release mutexes: Usually, while a process executes the code under mutex protection, some object's *invariants* are broken. This is why a mutex is needed: it prevents other processes to observe these broken invariants. So, by auto-releasing the mutex, you allow other processes to work in **inconsitent state**, which may crash the system futher. It is better to leave other processes to wait on a mutex forever, than allowing futher crashes.